# Slow boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot

I am a new Linux and I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS as my OS. I am encountering a slow boot of my OS. I am using Lenovo G50 (4Gb RAM, Core I5 processor). Pls. help, TIA! :)

Comment: You probably have to check the BIOS/UEFI settings and the power management settings. Don't have a lenovo to know. Also check the solutions provided in the possible duplicate question.
Last but not least welcome to Ubuntu :)

Comment: How slow is slow? We get these questions all the time and anything under a minuet is acceptable booting time on a mechanical HDD.

Comment: Hi! I have read this comment. Is this possible? hehe

"Believe it or not its the text output.

open a terminal and run:

sudo vi /etc/default/grub

change the line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"

run:

sudo update-grub2

It shaved 10 seconds off my 15 second boot time."

Answer (score 0):

I have read this comment. Is this possible? hehe.

Believe it or not its the text output.

open a terminal and run:

sudo vi /etc/default/grub

change the line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"

run:

sudo update-grub2

It shaved 10 seconds off my 15 second boot time.